# Determinant of hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $M=A+iB$ be a complex $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix. First of all we know that $$(\det M)^2=\det \begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}.$$ Also $\det \begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}$ is a polynomial in $n^2$ variables of degree $2n$. Is it true that $\det M$ is a polynomial, say D, of degree $n$ in this $n^2$ variables such that $D^2(M)=\det \begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}$? The explicit calculations for $n=1,2,3$ suggest so, yet I can't find the information if this is true neither proof this.

Comment: Are the matrices $A$ and $B$ here meant to be real? Also, where are you using the assumption that $M$ is a Hermitian matrix?

Comment: @Joppy Yes, they are real (this is a canonical decomposition of complex matrix). In many places, for example to have $n^2$ real variables (in general there is more) and to have complex determinant squared and not its modulus squared (for Hermitia I know that determinant is real).

Comment: Read about Pffafian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian

Comment: @openspace this looks promising yet I can't see how to end this from that information? The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}$ is not skew-symmetric.

Comment: What exactly are the $n^2$ variables? Is your question just whether $\det M$ is a polynomial in some variables?

Comment: @darijgrinberg the variables are entries of $A$ and $B$ the question is whether the complex polynomial in variables being entries of $M$ is in fact real polynomial of this new variables.

Answer (score -1):

The matrix is similar to

$$
S = T \hat{M} T^{-1}= 
\begin{pmatrix} I & iI \\ I & -iI \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac12I & \frac12 I\\-\frac i2I& \frac i2I\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} A+Bi &\\ &A-Bi \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} M &\\ &M^* \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} M &\\ &M \end{pmatrix}
$$
hence $S$ and $\hat M$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: I can't see why this solves the problem.

Comment: @J.E.M.S What is the determinant of the last block diagonal matrix?

Comment: ${\det M}^2$ how does it show that $\det M$ is a polynomial as conjectured?